# Showing that $\dim_FF[x]/\langle p \rangle=n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Given $F$ is a field and $p$ is a polynomial over $F$ with degree $n$. We let $\langle p\rangle$ be the principal ideal of all polynomials over $F$ which are multiples of $p$. I want to show that $\dim_FF[x]/\langle p \rangle=n$.

I don't really know where to start, I think I'm missing some understanding of the more "abstract algebra" parts of the question? I know what a principal ideal is, but maybe I'm having trouble bringing together what I've learned of rings with linear algebra?

An issue I'm having is that for a vector space $V$ with subspace $W$, we know that
$$
\dim(V/W) = \dim(V)-\dim(W)
$$
But because $F[x]$ is infinite-dimensional how can I land at $n$? If it was $F_n[x]$ it feels like it might be more straightforward? Any hints or help with the abstract algebra concepts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: $x^n$ is in $\bigoplus_{j=0}^{n-1} x^j F$.

Comment: Prove that $1,x,\dots,x^{n-1}$ is a basis of $F[x]/\langle p \rangle$ over $F$.

Comment: Show that the cosets $1+(p), x+(p),..., x^{n-1}+(p)$ form a basis over $F$.

Comment: Is it too hand-wavy to say that $F[x]/\langle p \rangle$ is the vector space of all polynomials mod polynomials of degree greater than or equal to $n$, so it's the same as $F_{n-1}[x]$ which has a nice basis? Or am I leaning to hard towards I guess an "isomorphic" type of agrument? @CHENRK

Comment: @AndreyYanyuk When you say vector spaces, you only consider addition and multiplication by elements of $F$. In this sense, $F[x]/\langle p\rangle$ is indeed isomorphic to the vector space formed by all polynomials of degree less than $n$ by the arithmetic modulo $p$.

Comment: Doesn't $p$ need to be irreducible here?

Comment: It's not given in the problem statement. Maybe I'm supposed to assume it? @mathematicalsamurai

Comment: I don't understand how to go about doing that, how can I show their linearly independent? I don't think I understand cosets very well to be fair @Mark